# Python "and" and "or" if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

In Python is it possible for me to code this and have it work as intended?

```
if a != None and b == None or a == None and b != None
```

basically I want to see if either a or b is None while the other isn't

Comment: Side note, the "correct" way of comparing to None is usually using ``is``, i.e. ``... a is not None and b is None ...``. Other than that your code should work as intended.

Answer (score 8):

Since it sounds like you want an `xor`...

```
if (a is None) != (b is None):
    ...
```

Comment: +1 You can write that as `if (a is None) is not (b is None):`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there can be only one instance of `NoneType` can exist, so you can use `is` operator, like this

```
if (a is None and b is not None) or (b is None and a is not None):
```

You can also count the number of `None`s like this

```
if (a, b).count(None) == 1:
```

Or you can explicitly check that like this

```
if a != b and (a is None or b is None):
```